# Responsive header relative to other elements on the page in pug file

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, pug

I have two questions concerning responsive layouts.

1. create a header over the page so that it has constant left and right margin no matter what the size of the browser is.
2. create a title in the center so that 1) it is centered, and 2) remains centered no matter what the size of the browser is.

Currently doing this with a predefined pug template, and the header pushes down the title element when it's inserted.

`layout.pug` is here:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
        include includes/head.pug
        //- block header

    body
        //- PRELOADER
        .page-loader
            .loader Loading...
        //- /PRELOADER


        //- problem: when the navbar is included: the title gets pushed down
        include includes/navbar.html

        block content
        //- block footer
        include includes/footer-js-files.pug
```

home.pug is here:

```
extends layout.pug

block content

  .wrapper
    include includes/video.pug
```

and finally `navbar.pug` here:F

```
<h3>
  <p style="text-align: left; width:49%; display: inline-block; font-weight: bold">
    XIAO LING
  </p>
  <p style="text-align: right; width:50%;  display: inline-block;">CV</p>
</h3>
```

Comment: again ... where is your questions ? what is your issue ? ... try to share a working code so we can see. You pug file contain only include of other files that we cannot see

Comment: Here's the github repo: https://github.com/lingxiao/Homepage/tree/master/public. the files are in public/bootstrap/assets